# Is intervening to prevent a charitable act a sin?

Tags: sin, charity

I once heard a religious practitioner (one who conducts Samskaras and so forth for lay Hindus) say that it is a sin to try to dissuade someone from giving charity.

is it supported by scripture?

Comment: yes - the event with shukracharya and mahabali attests to this. shukracharya tried to dissuade mahabali from giving, and lost an eye as result. in the same incident, mahabali disobeyed his guru and lost svarga as result. it was a lose-lose situation for both of them perfectly orchestrated by bhagavan.

Comment: It depends suppose giving charity bakasura likes should be stopped which will hurt our religious or spiritual progress

Answer (score 1):

Preventing charity certainly violates rules of polite behavior.

> The following eight are characteristic Sistacaras (rules of polite
> behavior): **charity**, truthfulness, penance, absence of greed, learning,
> sacrifice, procreation and sympathy.

**Vayu Purana I.59.37**

If charity is good conduct then preventing a charitable act is definitely not a good conduct.

**Is it a sin?**

We need to look at Gita Chapter 16 for the answer.

> It is deemed that the divine heritage leads to liberation and the
> demoniac to bondage. Grieve not, o son of Pandu! You are born to
> divine heritage.

**Gita 16.5**

> Men of demoniac nature know not what should be done and what should be
> avoided. Neither purity, **nor good conduct**, nor truthfulness is found
> in them.

**Gita 16.7**

> Holding such views, these lost souls - these men of little
> understanding - given, as they are, **to cruel deeds opposed to general
> well-being, appear as agents for the destruction of the world.**

**Gita 16.9**

> Steeped in insatiable lust, motivated by hypocrisy, vanity, arrogance
> and avarice, **given to corrupt and impure ways of life**, they work in
> pursuit of false values ascertained through delusion.

**Gita 16.10**

> Gripped by numerous bewildering thoughts, entangled in the meshes of
> delusion, and ever given to sex indulgences, they are degraded into
> states that are loathsome and full of suffering.

**Gita 16.16**

It would seem from the above verses that preventing charitable act would lead ultimately to a bad future. That seems to me to make preventing a charitable act a sin.

Answer (score 0):

Charitable act is a holy rite, generally done as a part of a sacred or holy vow. And creating obstacles in sacred-vows of someone, is sinful and results in a punishment in hell. Infact, a vow once taken by self, if not performed is considered sinful.

> Chapter 15, Part 1, Nārada Purāṇa
>
> अन्यैः संगृह्यमाणानांव्रतानां विघ्नकृन्नरः ॥
>  अतीव दुःखदंरौद्रं स
> याति श्लेष्मभोजनम् ॥ [१५ - ११८](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AB) ॥
>
> > 118. **A person who puts obstacles in the observance of holy vows that have been undertaken by others, falls into a hell named
> >      *śleṣmabhojana*, which is excessively terrible and leading to misery.**
>
> [English Translation](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n271/mode/1up?view=theater) by Motilal Banarsidass Publication.

Comment: not really an answer.

Comment: answer has nothing to do with charity.

Comment: Charity is a type of holy Vow @SK so the answer is correct

Comment: no, not every charity is done for some vow @Belucat

Comment: hmm oh ok, still...this is not completely wrong